# nodejs, How to send and receive files only through the server side?

Tags: node.js

How to send and receive files only through the server side in node.js?

the tools can be send a file by server side.
https://github.com/request/request

The example:

```
var path="json/test.json";
var formData = {
  file: fs.createReadStream(path),
};

var url='/send';  
request.post({
  url: url,
  formData: formData
});
```

I can send `test.json to` `'/send'`, 
and how to receive the file in other server side?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create receiver 
(required packages: "express", "multiparty")

```
var multiparty = require('multiparty');

module.exports = function(router) {

    router.post('/send', function (req, res, next) {
        var form = new multiparty.Form();

/* example:

        { file:
           [ { fieldName: 'package',
               originalFilename: 'test.json',
               path: '/var/folders/....',
               size: 14887812 } ]
        }
*/

        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            console.log(files); // do whatever you want with uploaded file(s)
        });
    });

    return router;
};
```